# How to get video thumbnail from YouTube URL and set it to image view in android

Tags: android, video, youtube, imageview, thumbnails

I want to create an application in which I want to play YouTube video. I want to get thumbnail from YouTube video URL which I have currently play in application and set it to image view. can any body help me with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [YouTube API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) to retrieve related **video thumbnail info** like title, image and length:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,snippet&fields=items/snippet(title,thumbnails),items/contentDetails/duration&key={{ YOUR_API_KEY }}&id={{ YOUR_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID }}
```

Or this `url` if you only want to get only thumbnail image with medium size:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,snippet&fields=items/snippet(title,thumbnails/medium/url),items/contentDetails/duration&key={{ YOUR_API_KEY }}&id={{ YOUR_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID }}
```

Your response may look like this:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "snippet": {
    "title": "F..k This S..t I'm Out",
    "thumbnails": {
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/5FjWe31S_0g/mqdefault.jpg"
     }
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT25S"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 39):

Use this url.. just replace with your youtude video id

```
String url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/"+{ID}+"/0.jpg";
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

**Option 1** – Get the custom thumbnail in 320 x 180 small image resolution

http://img.youtube.com/vi/{ID}/mqdefault.jpg

**Option 2** – Get the custom thumbnail in 480 x 360 standard image resolution

http://img.youtube.com/vi/{ID}/0.jpg

**Option 3** – Get the custom thumbnail in 720p or 1080p HD image resolution

http://img.youtube.com/vi/{ID}/maxresdefault.jpg

OR

just use YoutubeThumbnail API

Answer (score 2):

just do that

```
String thumbnailul = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" +videoid] + "/hqdefault.jpg";
 Glide.with(context).load(thumbnailul).into(holder.iv_thumbnail);
```